# Need SQL Server VLAN advice.. is it best practice to have all SQL Servers under 1 VLAN/network zone?

Tags: sql-server, network

Looking at the network placement of my SQL Servers. Looking for answers:

Is it a best practice to have all SQL Servers in 1 or 2 VLANs within your businesses network? however, if so, wont there potentially be performance issues on the NICs that manage that VLAN because there are so many SQL Servers in one VLAN?

Also on firewalls between the SQL Servers & application servers - this is not recommended right, As there will be a bottleneck from the firewall?

So going from the above comment, is it simply best practice to have the SQL servers in the same VLANs as the application servers that interact with the databases?

Comment: For an accurate answer you would need to specify what your goals are.  Security?  Performance?  Etc.  Also, the SQL Server being on the same VLAN--are the SQL Servers communicating with each other, or with app servers, or with workstations?  There is no best practice that will fit all environments and requirements.

Answer (score 4):

> Is it a best practice to have all SQL Servers in 1 or 2 VLANs within your businesses network?

This is enterprise and personal preference. Some enterprises setup areas for specific things, some don't. You might do it to ease certain administration items and others harder, but overall there isn't anything you specifically gain or lose from doing so.

> Also on firewalls between the SQL Servers & application servers - this is not recommended right, As there will be a bottleneck from the firewall?

This comes down to security requirements. Most enterprises have this in place, but again it's entirely dependent upon your requirements. If you have no requirements you may or may not choose to do this based on the security measures you'd like to enforce. Not everyone specifically wants all servers to be able to talk to all other servers on a network.